# In ASP.NET MVC can not get the DHCP assigned IP address of clients Which visits my website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ip, ip-address

Trying to access the clients ip address of another PC from my website build in ASP.NET MVC.
I have used the bellow properties of .NET but still it's sending the IP address of clients always 127.0.0.1 as I have checked the IP assigned by the DHCP server is different.

- Request.UserHostAddress
- Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
- Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]

all of the above codes return 127.0.0.1 but the real IP address you can see in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are accessing your website locally through localhost or 127.0.0.1.
In that case your client reachs your server via private network and the server can only see 127.0.0.1.

Comment: No I am accessing it from another PC through public IP generated by Conveyor extension in visual studio which allows you to access your debugging site publicly. but yeah both PC's (server and client) are in the same network.